# Implicit conversion loses floating point precision: 'double' to 'float'; fix?

Tags: ios, implicit-conversion

I've downloaded the `CMUnistrokeGestureRecognizer` which appears to have a few errors, and Im trying to fix them, one of the errors is `Implicit conversion loses floating point precision: 'double' to 'float'` during this line of code;

```
CGFloat scale = fminf(rect.size.width / pathAnalysis.pathRect.size.width, rect.size.height / pathAnalysis.pathRect.size.height);
```

The full block is ;

```
- (CMUDBezierPathInfo)bezierPathInfoToFitRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CMUDPathAnalysis pathAnalysis;
    pathAnalysis.pathRect = CGRectZero;
    pathAnalysis.startPoint = CGPointMake(-1.0f, -1.0f); // i.e. undefined

    CGPathApply(self.bezierPath.CGPath, &pathAnalysis, CMUDCGPathApplierFunc);

    CGFloat scale = fminf(rect.size.width / pathAnalysis.pathRect.size.width, rect.size.height / pathAnalysis.pathRect.size.height);
    CGPoint translation = CGPointMake(-pathAnalysis.pathRect.origin.x + (rect.size.width/2.0f - scale*pathAnalysis.pathRect.size.width/2.0f),
                  -pathAnalysis.pathRect.origin.y + (rect.size.height/2.0f - scale*pathAnalysis.pathRect.size.height/2.0f));

    CMUDBezierPathInfo bezierPathInfo;
    bezierPathInfo.startPoint = pathAnalysis.startPoint;
    bezierPathInfo.scaleToFit = scale;
    bezierPathInfo.translationToFit = translation;

    return bezierPathInfo;
}
```

I have tried typecasting, but it does not work;

```
CGFloat scale = (CGFloat)fminf(rect.size.width / pathAnalysis.pathRect.size.width, rect.size.height / pathAnalysis.pathRect.size.height);
```

**EDIT**

`CMDPathAnalysis` is defined like so;

```
typedef struct {
CGRect pathRect;
CGPoint startPoint;
} CMUDPathAnalysis;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C code, you can use the macros MIN and MAX which will produce a result with the same type as the parameters; they are defined in the same header file that defines YES and NO. They are quite useful for CGFloat which has different type depending on whether you are compiling for 32 or 64 bits.

For example:

```
CGFloat scale = MIN(rect.size.width / pathAnalysis.pathRect.size.width, 
                    rect.size.height / pathAnalysis.pathRect.size.height);
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're passing values of type `double` to `fminf()`, when the function prototype is:

```
float fminf(float x, float y);
```

Your passed-in values are therefore being implicitly cast to type `float` and hence the error you are getting.

Try using `fmin()` instead of `fminf()`. `fmin()` takes double-precision arguments:

```
 double fmin(double x, double y);
```

Note the definition of CGFloat is architecture-specific:

```
/* Definition of `CGFLOAT_TYPE', `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE', `CGFLOAT_MIN', and `CGFLOAT_MAX'. */

#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE double
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 1
# define CGFLOAT_MIN DBL_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX DBL_MAX
#else
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE float
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 0
# define CGFLOAT_MIN FLT_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX FLT_MAX
#endif

typedef CGFLOAT_TYPE CGFloat;
```

If you were on a 32-bit architecture, `fminf()` would've been OK, but for portability it is best to use `fmin()` unless you know you are only ever going to be passing in a `float`.

Comment: please see the above edit of the definition of `CMDPathAnalysis`

Comment: @DevC You could try using the `MIN()` macro as suggested by @gnasher729, although I'm slightly bemused as to why my solution doesn't work...

Comment: I am too, there is a lot of problems with the library as it is outdated so it may be dependency issues. I felt typecasting should have fixed it originally

Comment: It's possible the arguments to `fmin()` could be +/-`INF` since `pathAnalysis.pathRect` is initialised to `CGRectZero` and its `width` / `height` used as denominators in the inline division. But whilst this isn't really desirable, it shouldn't cause the error you're seeing. I suggest first assigning the inline arithmetic to intermediate variables then inspecting their values by setting a breakpoint in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. @gnasher729 answer worked, no more error.